# Create canvas gradients from gradients

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, gradient

I'm trying to create a day/night scene, using two radial gradients. The issue arises when I try to create a linear gradient from my two gradients; they are invalid CSS values. Is there any way I can do this, or do I need to find a new hobby?

Basically where it goes wrong:

```
var skygrad = ctx.createLinearGradient(0,500,500,500);
skygrad.addColorStop(0,"daygrad");
skygrad.addColorStop(1,"nightgrad");
```

Comment: I'd have to see more of your code, but something like that is not really possible. You'd have to do a work around of laying the div with parts transparent or do one big gradient I think, not exactly sure what you're going for. Could you provide more info?

Comment: What I was going for was a linear gradient, that I would later rotate, with half as 'day' and 'night', which would be radial gradients with a lighter center for the sun/moon. They would then rotate in the background to create the effect of a day to night transition. I am going for one big gradient, in the end, but I don't see how _one_ big gradient would be at all possible with what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Sounds like you're in need of CSS animation for that type of background animation to me. the rest can be done on canvas depending on what you're trying to accomplish. An outline or picture or something would help me help you further

Comment: You won't be able to achieve this effect by rotating a large gradient. First, the color stops needs color values so you'd need to define the complete gradient. Second, the atmospheric colors doesn't simply rotate. F.ex. the day colors are blue above us and light in the horizon. If you simply wanted to rotate the light horizon would eventually be above us which is not how it works. Or the other way, the darker blue would be in the horizon where it's suppose to be orange/red at sunset etc. etc. You will need to animate the gradient between the proper colors for this to work.

Comment: And third, unless you want this be happen at equator you would also need to move the sun/moon diagonally while "rotating".